# Run a python image processing script in an android app

Tags: android, python, opencv

I am using a python script to detect circles using Hough transfrom which imports "opencv2" and "math" libraries.Can I run this script in an android app?How can this be done?The following application is the one I want to run in an android app.`import cv2
import math

```
def resizeImage(img):
    dst=cv2.resize(img,None,fx=1,fy=1,interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return dst
img=cv2.imread('20140318_174800.jpg')
grey=cv2.imread('20140318_174800.jpg',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(grey,50,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(thresh,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,75,param1=50,param2=13,minRadius=0,maxRadius=400)
for i in circles[0,:]:
    #draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    #draw the centre of the circle
    cv2.circle(img,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

##Determine co-ordinates for centre of circle
x1 = circles[0][0][0]
y1 = circles[0][0][1]
#x2 = circles[0][1][0]
#y2 = circles[0][1][1]
##Angle betwen two circles
#theta = math.degrees(math.atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)))

##print information
print "x1 = ",x1
print "y1 = ",y1
#print "x2 = ",x2
#print "y2 = ",y2

#print theta
print circles

##Resize image
img = resizeImage(img)
thresh = resizeImage(thresh)
##Show Images 
cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)
cv2.imshow("img",img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

`

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

atm, you can't.

you would have to recompile the cv2 module for android first, in a similar way python4android does it(redirecting system calls to java rmi), tough job.